# wordpress theme installing issue from a .zip file

Tags: wordpress-theming

While I was installing a theme for Wordpress from .zip file, I got this error:

```
Warning: POST Content-Length of 11979500 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's default max post size is `8MB` (or `8388608 bytes`).

You need to change/set the `post_max_size` variable inside of your php.ini file. You just need to set it to more than `12MB` for this particular file.

For example:

```
post_max_size=16M
```

Alternatively, you could upload the zip file through FTP to your `/wp-content/themes/` folder and activate from inside of the WordPress Admin Panel.